# Why 'insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete assignment' syntax error occurs?

Tags: java, android

```
public Object execute() throws Exception {
    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();     
    DBHelper dbh = new DBHelper(mContext);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        Cursor cursor_products = db.rawQuery(dbh.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS,null);    

        //Cursor cursor_products = db.query(DBHelper.PRODUCT_TABLE, new String[]{DBHelper.PRODUCT_ID,DBHelper.PRODUCT_NAME,DBHelper.PRODUCT_PRICE,DBHelper.PRODUCT_QTY}, null, null, null, null, DBHelper.PRODUCT_NAME + " ASC" );
        while(cursor_products.moveToNext()){
            JSONObject product = new JSONObject();
            product.put("id", cursor_products.getInt(0));
            product.put("name", cursor_products.getString(1));
            product.put("price", cursor_products.getInt(2));
            product.put("stock", cursor_products.getInt(3));
            result.put(product);
        }
        cursor_products.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName()+"@54", e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        db.close();
        dbh.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using the above code, the error occurs at the line: `Cursor cursor_products = db.rawQuery(dbh.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS,null);`
which is really weird because im sure my assignments are correct.
Is there a chance that its only Eclipse not parsing the code correctly?

Comment: Try modifying the statement slightly and see what changes.

Comment: i removed the commented line below it and added a space between `dbh.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS,null` such that it looks like `dbh.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS, null` and the error disappeared... argh

Comment: Neither of those actions would fix the error, as all you did was change what the compiler sees as whitespace. Clearly there was something else odd in the source code.

Comment: I believe you may be complaining not about the Java compiler, but about the Eclipse editor's syntax analyzer?  I recall that it sometimes expects spaces in parm lists, for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

//Try this

`Cursor cursor_products = db.rawQuery(GET_ALL_PRODUCTS,null);`